# Domain Mapping in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache, url, mod-rewrite, dns

I have already spent hours on this, and i don't make any progress. How can i mask or map my WordPress page into my sub-domain without re installing the whole WordPress files again? I have tried those multi-site plugins and it gave me a fresh copy of WordPress! I don't want that.

I have also tried the WPMU domain mapping plugin, but the subdomain outputs the homepage.

What i want is:

e.g i want my  URL `www.mysite.com/mypage` to become `mypage.mysite.com`

Is this even possible? Also, I have already created a wildcard sub-domain in my cPanel.

NOTE* This will be only for 1 page only.

here's my current `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mypage\.domain\.com\.es$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com.es/mypage/ [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What was that? can you be more specific?

Comment: In the Wordpress backend, you have a tab for general options where you can change the URL of your site. Depending on the version, you may also need to change a value in the wp_options table

Comment: This will be only for 1 page only. I dont want to change the whole URL of my site.